# Algorithm: Remove minium weight sum of edges to make a Weighted diagraph no cycles

Tags: graph-theory, algorithms

1. All edge weights are positive.
2. Exists multiple edges between two vertexes

Example:
Geive 4 Vertexes and 5 egdegs

```
A1 -> A2 => 1
A2 -> A3 => 4
A3 -> A1 => 2
A4 -> A2 => 1
A3 -> A4 => 3
```

just remove `A1 -> A2` and `A4 -> A2`

For simple case, simple graph, one cycle, the question is easy to solve by  removing cycle minimum weight egde.
For complex case, if two cycle have common edges, this situation become complex, I didn't find a effient algorithm to solve this problem.

Comment: Welcome to MSE.  You'll get a lot more help, and fewer votes to close, if you show that you have made a real effort to solve the problem yourself.  What are your thoughts?  What have you tried?  How far did you get?  Where are you stuck?  This question is likely to be closed if you don't add more context.  Please respond by **editing the question body.**  Many people browsing questions will vote to close without reading the comments.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want to produce a maximum spanning tree. It maximizes the sum of edge-weights used in a graph that has no cycles, thereby minimizing the sum of edge-weights **not** used (i.e., removed).

You could use Kruskal's or Prim's algorithm, which inherently finds a minimum spanning tree, but you can modify it to find a maximum spanning tree instead. For example, go through a sorted listed of edges in descending order of edge-weight. Add the current edge to the graph if it connects two previously unconnected vertices, otherwise, skip it (i.e., remove it from the input graph).

Comment: Make a graph no cycle not make a spanning tree, due to the diapgh directed edge. i.e. Grpah A -> B, A -> C, B -> C；there no cycle，but this cannot be a spaning tree.